# NLP Sentiments: Giving wrong result when using negative word in positive way

Tags: node.js, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am using `NodeJs` to create my application with the help of [sentiment lib](https://github.com/thisandagain/sentiment)

The problem is that it is giving wrong results when a negative word is used in a positive manner.

```
var sentiment = require('sentiment');

var result = sentiment('I am dying to eat a kitkat!');
console.dir(result);
```

> { score: -3,   comparative: -0.42857142857142855,   tokens: [ 'i',
>   'am', 'dying', 'to', 'eat', 'a', 'kitkat' ],   words: [ 'dying' ],
>   positive: [],   negative: [ 'dying' ] }

```
///or

result = sentiment('your internet is not bad', knowladgeBase);
console.dir(result);
```

> { score: -3,   comparative: -0.6,   tokens: [ 'your', 'internet',
>   'is', 'not', 'bad' ],   words: [ 'bad' ],   positive: [],   negative:
>   [ 'bad' ] }

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to implement a sentiment analysis system by yourself than try using another library. But if you are interested in implementing one, here is a solution.
In a basic manner, sentiment analysis systems use two approaches to solve the problem.
 - Lexicon-based approaches
 - corpus-based approaches

The library you are using, uses a simple lexicon-based algorithm. If you want to have a more advanced system use a sentiment lexicon such as [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it) or [SenticNet](http://sentic.net) together with Part-Of-Speech (POS) tagging. 
You can find negative and positive words. Then use some simple rules. 
- If a negative word has came with a negative verb, the statement is positive.
- If a negative word has came with a positive verb, the statement is negative. 
- If a positive word has came with a positive verb, the statement is positive.
- If a positive word has came with a negative verb, the statement is negative.

Comment: **Alikbar** many thanks for you insight, I have upvoted but not accepted this answer, just in case if anyone can post a `lib`. If after some day I don't find any better answer then I accept yours.