# Why negative sentences have the same polarity as a positive sentences in Sentiment analysis with TextBlob?

Tags: nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I'm using TextBlob for Sentiment analysis and observed this --

The positive sentence is: 
**She is that good at this.**

Its sentiment analysis is:
**polarity=0.7**, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001

The negative sentence is:
**She isn't that good at this.**

Its sentiment analysis is:
**polarity=0.7**, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001

I understand Subjectivity could be same(or almost same) but how could polarity be the same? Isn't the second sentence negative?

Here's the code as requested:

```
analysis = TextBlob("She isn't that good at this")
print (analysis.sentiment)
```

Comment: Well, it appears that TextBlob isn't that good at this, either. Or you messed up your code, but you'd have to show what you did in order for us to help.

Comment: In general: don't judge the system on a handful of made-up toy sentences; get a bigger set of labelled real-world sentences and run a test to see if it is doing any good.

Comment: @lenz I've updated the post with the code

Comment: Look, if TextBlob's sentiment analysis isn't good enough, you have to find a better tool. But that isn't a topic for Stack Overflow...

Comment: Look at this answer I gave before : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41480582/5575289